# Swift 5 JSON Import with CodingKeys and ENUM values

Tags: swift

Reading in from small JSON file (cut/pasted small sample) and bring it into structs. I am using CodingKeys to change the "string key" to match what I want in the struct. I am changing the "whoresponds" key to "respondingPilot". That is all working fine. However, I also want to look at the values on that property and change on-the-fly the value brought in. For example, if I get the string "BOTH", I want to change my data that is stored to "CAPT & F/O". Same if I see "FO", I want that changed to "F/O" as it read in. Sample below reads in fine but will not make the changes. Still learning but must be something simple I am missing. Thanks!

```
struct CheckListsJSON: Codable {
    var name: String
    var checklistItems: [ChecklistItemsJSON]
}

struct ChecklistItemsJSON: Codable, Identifiable {
    var challenge: String
    var respondingPilot: PilotResponding

    let id = UUID()

    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case challenge
        case respondingPilot = "whoresponds"
    }

    enum PilotResponding: String, Codable {
        case CPT = "CAPT"
        case FO  = "F/O"
        case PF  = "PF"
        case PM  = "PM"
        case BOTH = "CAPT & F/O"
    }
}

let jsonAC = "{\"name\": \"After Start\", \"checklistItems\": [{\"challenge\": \"Generators\", \"whoresponds\": \"CPT\"}, {\"challenge\": \"Isolation Valve\", \"whoresponds\": \"FO\"}}"

let fileData = Data(jsonAC.utf8)

do {
    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CheckListsJSON.self, from: fileData)
    print("decoded:", decodedData)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoding a string to an enum works like `CodingKeys`. The `raw value` is the string you receive and the `case` is the case.

Unfortunately the character set of enum cases is restricted. Space characters, `/` and `&` are not allowed.

You could write something like this, raw values which match the case can be omitted.

```
enum PilotResponding: String, Codable {
    case CAPT = "CPT"
    case F_O  = "FO"
    case PF, PM
    case CAPT_F_O = "BOTH"
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Ah, so what is coming in from the JSON is on the "right" side of = in the enum and what I want is on the "left".  Seems backward but it works as you say.  I am now going to load to CoreData so permanently stored. Because of the character restrictions, I could always use a "case" to make the changes as I load to CoreData correct?

Comment: As I said "left" and "right" is exactly the same as in `CodingKeys`. And I don't understand your statement regarding CoreData.

Comment: Got it on left and right.  I mentioned CoreData because what I am doing is importing in JSON data and then going to "fill out" CoreData entities with the data.  Just import once and save/edit permanent on device in CoreData.  If I need to add more similar data (another aircraft), then just import once and add to CoreData.  Hope that explains it better.